# Acumatica Custom Combine Sales Sub

Tags: acumatica

I would like to add a custom value for Order type sales sub account and use it like the standard combinations of sub accounts.

I tried overriding the SOSalesAcctSubDefault but I can't add the custom value.

I would like to add, for example, 'DDD' in the subaccount combinations.

[Attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7a0U.png)

[CombineSalesSub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwmqV.png)

[CombineSalesSubField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cAjr.png)